# Validate a field globaly at laravel 5

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-request

Let's say we have a same field in almost all tables with same rules for validation, for example something like *slug*, is it possible to create a rule to handle validation for all requests with the slug field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one main [Request validation class](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation) and use it in all controllers and in requests you need more rules you can inherit from this main Request class to add more rules

Comment: @Mic0 Sorry but if you want to user Laravel5 and generally PHP you should definitely look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php to learn them.

Comment: I created a class *MainRequest* and i extend it from *Request* class, then i put a protected $validation variable within this class which contains global rules and within my custom request class which they extends MainRequest i add other rules to $this->validation variable and at the enf i return it at rules() method, i don't know if it's the right approach but it's working. thanks.